# When is the set of tensors of rank at most $r$ closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, multilinear-algebra

Consider the vector space $V=A_1\otimes A_2\otimes\dots\otimes A_k$ where $k\geq 2$ and let $\sigma_r$ be the set of tensors in $V$ of rank at most $r$. It seems clear that $\sigma_r$ is Zariski (Euclidean?) closed in the following cases :

1 - $k=2$ and $r$ is anything

2 - $r=1$ and $k$ is anything

3 - $\sigma_r=V$

Is this list complete? Can I change the third case as $r=\prod_{i=1}^k \dim A_i$ and if not with some other integral condition on $r$?

Comment: What is your definition for rank of a tensor?

Comment: A rank one tensor is a tensor $T\in V$ of the form $T=a_1\otimes a_2\otimes\dots\otimes a_k$. The rank of a tensor $T$ is the smallest number $r$ such that $T$ can be written as the sum of $r$ rank one tensors.

Comment: If $V$ has the structure of a finite dimensional (real hausdorff) topological vector space, then: yes. Since you mention the Zariski topology (and euclidean?) I am not sure what your setting is.

Comment: Above, each $A_i$ is a finite dimensional complex vector space hence $V$ admits the Zariski topology.

Comment: You have to specify which topology you are working with: Zariski topology or Euclidean topology. I think the answer to your question depends on this.

Comment: I work with the Zariski topology. I wrote Euclidean to show my curiosity also with the Euclidean case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all, the maximal possible rank of degree $k$ tensors is bounded from above by
   $$
   R=\prod_{i=1}^{k-1} dim(A_i).
   $$ 
   Here and below the indices are arranged so that 
   $$2\le n_1= dim(A_1)\le n_2= dim(A_2)\le ...\le n_k= dim(A_k).$$

See for instance

M.V. Catalisano, A.V. Geramita, A. Gimigliano, 
"Ranks of tensors, secant varieties of Segre varieties and fat points", 
Linear Algebra Appl. 355 (2002) 263-285.

This bound is better than the one that you wrote in the last part of your question. In particular,  $\sigma_R$ equals the entire tensor product
$$
V= A_1\otimes ... \otimes A_k,
$$
which is, of course, Zariski closed.

2. There are some Zariski closed examples besides the ones that you listed. For instance (I am working over ${\mathbb C}$), 
   consider  triples
   $$
   (n_1,n_2,n_3)= (2, 2, n), n\ge 4. 
   $$
   Then in $V={\mathbb C}^2 \otimes {\mathbb C}^2 \otimes {\mathbb C}^n$, 
   all tensors of rank =4 also have the border rank =4, see Table 10.3.1 on page 253 of

J.Landsberg, "[Tensors: Geometry and Applications](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-128)", AMS, 2011.

This means that the set $\sigma_3\subset V$ of tensors of rank $\le 3$ is closed. (In contrast, $\sigma_2$ is not closed.) 
At the same time, since $n\ge 4$, $V=\sigma_4\ne \sigma_3$.

I very much doubt that a complete list of tuples $(n_1,...,n_k,r)$ for which $\sigma_r$ is Zariski closed is known. Among general results on lack of closedness in the classical topology the following is known, see

V. De Silva, L.-H. Lim, "Tensor rank and the ill-posedness of the best low-rank approximation problem," SIAM J. Matrix Anal. Appl. 30 (2008) 1084-1127.

Theorem. Suppose $k\ge 3$ and 
$$
2\le r\le \min(n_1,...,n_k).
$$
Then $\sigma_r$ is not closed in the classical topology. (Hence, it is not closed in the Zariski topology either.)